# Where can I change my xdebug settings in PHP 5.4.x

Tags: php, xdebug

I remember in PHP 5.3 I could easily change xdebug settings inside php.ini file. (i.e. xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200)

I have upgraded to PHP 5.4 and since then no longer I can modify xdebug settings.
I make changes in php.ini and restart the webserver but nothing happens.

Looking inside php.ini there is no definition for xdebug settings.
but when I run:

```
php -m
```

I see xdebug already loaded.

Surprisingly when I run:

```
php -i | grep xdebug
```

I see loads of xdebug settings.

So my question is where are those settings come from if they are not in php.ini
(I need to add I have checked /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini already and there is onlu one line in it: zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20100525/xdebug.so)

And how can I modify these settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the same like before. Open a `phpinfo` and look which ini files are loaded. In one of that files should be a xdebug part and you can modify them. If there is not block for xdebug you can add them. You can put that settings to the `20-xdebug.ini` if you but if there are some other settings and the order is not correct your changes aren't working.

Comment: Thanks Stony. Adding the settings to 20-xdebug.ini file did the trick.